pylint unable to find imports from currently active virtual environment
I recently setup my nvim environment and I can’t seem to figure out why pylint complains that it's unable to import the module installed in my envrionment.

The LSP in general works fine, I can even go to definition of the arcade import. I verified that Neovim seems to be aware of my poetry environment by running this command
!which python it returns the poetry env path
/Users/darren/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/simple-platformer-grm8zU49-py3.12/bin/python

the poetry env also shows in my path when running this command in Neovim :echo $PATH
This is my LSP config
I also did the :checkhealth and :LspInfo and both seems fine to me.

Is LSP even used to communicate with pylint? AFAIK, you just filter your code through it and capture the output. Anyhow, pylint needs to be installed in the venv and it doesn't matter whether pylint is run from Neovim or the terminal. There are several duplicate questions about it on SO, where this question belongs. I'm voting to close as off-topic.

One more thought, since you're already using poetry, you could just add pylint as a dev dependency and call it a day.

Please don’t post images of text

After further debugging, I find out that this error I am seeing is not from pyright but instead it is from pylint.
This seems to be a known issue as quoted in pylint-venv:
Pylint does not respect the currently activated virtualenv if it is not installed in every virtual environment individually. This module provides a Pylint init-hook to use the same Pylint installation with different virtual environments.
Solution 1: nvim way

install pylint-venv, this will serve as a hook to your pylon config
add the pylon-venv path to your nvim lint config

A more detailed post regarding this was posted by
serranomorante, in his git dotfiles repo.
This is his dotfile changes for nvim-lint specifically.
Solution 2: easy way project level

add this to either .pylintrc or pyproject.toml

init-hook="
    exec 'aW1wb3J0IHN5cywgb3MKCmlmICdWSVJUVUFMX0VOVicgbm90IGluIG9zLmVudmlyb246CiAgICBz \
    eXMuZXhpdCgwKQoKdmVfZGlyID0gb3MuZW52aXJvblsnVklSVFVBTF9FTlYnXQp2ZV9kaXIgaW4g \
    c3lzLnBhdGggb3Igc3lzLnBhdGguaW5zZXJ0KDAsIHZlX2RpcikKYWN0aXZhdGVfdGhpcyA9IG9z \
    LnBhdGguam9pbihvcy5wYXRoLmpvaW4odmVfZGlyLCAnYmluJyksICdhY3RpdmF0ZV90aGlzLnB5 \
    JykKCiMgRml4IGZvciB3aW5kb3dzCmlmIG5vdCBvcy5wYXRoLmV4aXN0cyhhY3RpdmF0ZV90aGlz \
    KToKICAgIGFjdGl2YXRlX3RoaXMgPSBvcy5wYXRoLmpvaW4ob3MucGF0aC5qb2luKHZlX2Rpciwg \
    J1NjcmlwdHMnKSwgJ2FjdGl2YXRlX3RoaXMucHknKQoKZXhlY2ZpbGUoYWN0aXZhdGVfdGhpcywg \
    ZGljdChfX2ZpbGVfXz1hY3RpdmF0ZV90aGlzKSkK'.decode('base64')"


Where the base64 encoded string decodes to
import sys, os

if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' not in os.environ:
    sys.exit(0)

ve_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
ve_dir in sys.path or sys.path.insert(0, ve_dir)
activate_this = os.path.join(os.path.join(ve_dir, 'bin'), 'activate_this.py')

# Fix for windows
if not os.path.exists(activate_this):
    activate_this = os.path.join(os.path.join(ve_dir, 'Scripts'), 'activate_this.py')

execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

